# Php send mail speed

Tags: php, email

I have coded a normal send mail functionality in  my php code for password recovery .
The code works fine and I am able to send and receive mails...
The only problem is speed and time.
I receive mail from my server  after approx an hour late.
what should i do to receive mails instantaneously .

My php code goes like :

```
mail($user_email, "Password", $message,
"From:admin <admin@example.com>\r\n" .
 "X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion());
```

Comment: check the mail headers, see if it sets on a server anywhere - this is probably a mail server issue not your code, what mail server are you using? where is it hosted? have you contacted your host?

Comment: Check the received message headers in your received mail, to determine if the problem is at your end or the recipient's

Comment: thanks for answering ...
I'm using Mochahost vps server.

Answer (score 2):

This is most likely not an issue in PHP but rather an issue with your hosting provider.  Some shared hosts queue emails before sending them.  In particular GoDaddy is horrible about this...so if that happens to be your webhost, then that is the issue.  I have seen their email take 3-4 hours sometimes on a cheap shared linux server.

Comment: i'm using mochahost vps ... should i contact them for this

Comment: yes.  also you can get some cues from your email header (once you receive one...view the full header source and see what the timestamps are on each bounce).  my money is on your web-host doing something strange.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the emails you send are clean for SPAM filters. You must have a good reputation for your emails to be delivered properly. When you code your own email sender script, make sure to:

1. Format the *to* email as "John Doe " and not just "john.doe@example.org". SPAM filters like to see that you know the sender names.
2. Use the same *reply-to* email address. If it is added to your recipients contact list, that's one of the best way to pass SPAM filters.
3. If you email is formatted in HTML, make sure the HTML is clean and add an alternative text.
4. Check if the IP address of the SMTP server has a good reputation.

I also recommend to use the service of a third part specialised in delivering emails like [MailChimp](http://mailchimp.com) who has a good reputation (from ISPs point of view) and where you can open an account for free and send transactional emails (in addition of sending newsletters). They have an API which allow you to couple your application with their system.